# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8]

Tags: json, python-2.7

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

url = "http://ajax/googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
query = raw_input ("What do you want to search for ? >> ")
query = urllib.urlencode({'q': query})
response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query).read()
data = json.loads (response)
results = data ['responseData'] ['results']
for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']
    print (title + ';' + url)
```

ERROR
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/dragonleo/PycharmProjects/untitled2/googleapi
What do you want to search for ? >> apple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dragonleo/PycharmProjects/untitled2/googleapi", line 8, in 
    response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query).read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1181, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1156, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError:

Appreciate if expert can explain why I am getting the error

Comment: Added the last time in the error                                                    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Answer (score 1):

Two problems stand out immediately:

1. There are multiple typos in the code above.  Specifically, there are no spaces between brackets and parens.  Also, the URL should be ajax.googleapis.com.
2. The Google Web Search API is no longer available. You should migrate to the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.